# corona sdk - screen boundaries - PLEASE ASSIST

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The following is a snippet of code I copied from a different web site. I dont understand how this particular screen boundary code snippet is working and would appreciate some help, please.

```
local bottomWall = display.newRect(320, 0, 1, 480)
local leftWall = display.newRect(0, 480, 320, 1)
local rightWall = display.newRect(0, -1, 320, 1)
local topWall = display.newRect(-1, 0, 1, 480)
```

Can anyone please explain this in detail? I dont understand the parameters... Im having trouble creating boundaries for my app. My apps dimensions are 1920 by 1080...Please keep any replies very simple (no technical lingo, please)....Imagine you are teaching someone who has been living under a rock for centuries and now has just come out! - Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I'm largely unfamiliar with corona but that code just appears to be making for "wall" rectangles. I would assume there was code somewhere else to hook up behaviours for those rectangles.

Comment: Have you looked at the Corona docs for `newRect`? If not, then you should do that first. Then, after you've played around with the above numbers to see how they affect the position and size of the walls, see if you can guess what you should replace them with in your case. If you have issue doing that, then post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all about newRect in Corona:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newRect.html